# window.location.href doesn't work when using vue.js?

Tags: angularjs, vue.js

When I use angular.js, I use `$.ajax` in methods, then `window.location.href` when it succeeds. It works.

But when I use vue.js, it doesn't work until I add `window.event.returnValue = false;` after it.

I think it has nothing to do with angular.js or vue.js, because I use `$.ajax`, not `$http` or others. But why doesn't it work when I use vue.js?

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'xxx',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    async : false,
    data: {
        'xxx' : xxx
    },
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.status == 'success') {
            window.location.href = 'xxx';
            // window.event.returnValue = false;
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        xxx
    }
});
```

Comment: If you are using Vue Router, you should be doing something like this instead in your component: `this.$router.push({name: 'name-of-the-route'})` or if your route does not have a name `this.$router.push({path: '/my-url'})`. See https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this. It work perfectly for me.

```
 created() {
            this.vm = @Json.Serialize(Model)  
            this.ppp = window.location;          
            this.path = this.ppp.pathname;           
            this.lastid = this.path.lastIndexOf("/");
            this.id = this.path.charAt((this.lastid + 1));
            this.url = this.ppp.origin + '/Controller/Action/' + this.id;
            console.log(this.url)
            axios.get(this.url)
                    .then(response => { this.summary = response.data });
        },
        data:
        {
            vm: [],  
            summary:[],
            ppp:'',
            id:0,
            url:'',
           
            
        }
```

Hope this help

Comment: Code-only answers generally aren't very helpful. This one in particular *needs* an explanation as to how it solves the problem. I can't see how this relates to the question at all.